# What does it mean that a function has been added in multiple versions of node?

Tags: node.js

For example [dns.setDefaultResultOrder](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnssetdefaultresultorderorder) has been added in versions v16.4.0 and v14.18.0

Does it mean that it had been deleted in one of the versions between them?

If yes, why would it be deleted instead of deprecated?

Comment: v15, like all odd-numbered versions of Node, wasn't LTS, so v14 kept being maintained and 14.18.0 specifically (2021-09-28) was released _after_ 15.14.0 (2021-04-06) - https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule, https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/. v15 never had that function to deprecate or delete, as you can see on https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/dns.html#dnssetdefaultresultorderorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both version 14 and 16 are LTS, as visible here https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md so this function have been added in both versions because both version are still supported.